# Kernel testing a function that calls render()

Tags: 8, testing

I have a kernel test that is testing the render array method for a table within a controller.

In this method I have added a dropbutton for an actions column. For this to display correctly in the table column, you need to call the `render()` function on that cell before returning the rest of the render array.

```
    [
          'title'   => 'Title',
          'bundle'  => 'My content Type',
          'date'    => '15/10/2019',
          'actions' => render([
              '#type'  => 'dropbutton',
              '#links' => [
                'action_1' => [
                  'title' => $this->t('Action 1'),
                  'url'   => Url::fromRoute('myRoute1'),
                ],
                'action_2'   => [
                  'title' => $this->t('Action 2'),
                  'url'   => Url::fromRoute('myRoute2'),
                ],
              ],
            ]),
    ];
```

This works fine when viewing the page, but in a kernel test I get:

```
LogicException : Render context is empty, because render() was called outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use renderPlain()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead.
```

Using either `renderRoot()` or `renderPlain()` causes the test to pass, but renders the links as individual anchor tags rather then in a drop button.

Is there a different way to render items inside a table render array that will still allow the method to be testable?

Comment: Avoid early rendering in a controller, if possible. Usually it helps adding a data key to the table cell: `'actions' => ['data' => ['#type' => ...`

Comment: @4k4 Absolute genius! Thank you so much for that :D